# Is this a bug in plotting step functions?

Tags: plotting

The following simple code generates a flawed plot:

```
f[t_] := UnitStep[t - 14.1] + UnitStep[t - 14.5] + UnitStep[t - 14.9]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

I never expected part of the connection is slanted.  Although I can fix this issue in many ways (such as using PlotPoints option, changing the plot ranges),  this behavior is still surprising to me.  Could anyone explain this?
 (I'm using Mathematica 11.3)

Comment: Please try to avoid using the bugs tag unless it has been confirmed as a bug by Wolfram or the community agrees that this is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

```
f[t_] := UnitStep[t - 14.1] + UnitStep[t - 14.5] + UnitStep[t - 14.9]
```

Adding [`Exclusions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html) will cause [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to look closely in the region of the `Exclusions` and result in clean steps.

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16},
 Exclusions -> {14.1, 14.5, 14.9},
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** You will get the same result with `Exclusions -> True`. **END EDIT**

Or use the option [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16},
 MaxRecursion -> 10,
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**   We can use a special form `{numberofpoints, {list of points}}`  for the option setting for `PlotPoints` as an alternative to setting a very large value (see [see this answer by Ullrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200046/125)):

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16}, Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotPoints -> {50, {14.1, 14.5, 14.9}}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Add the option `PlotPoints` with a large value:

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Quiet @ Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 16}, Filling -> Axis, Exclusions -> None, 
  Method -> {"MaxBend" -> 0}]
```

> same picture