# Why does plot not show where Piecewise function is not zero?

Tags: plotting, piecewise, sampling

From my user point view this looks like bug. But I am not an expert.

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:=Piecewise[{{1,x==1},{0,True}}];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

Does not show `1` at `x=1`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I just type

```
 Plot[Piecewise[{{1, x == 1}, {0, True}}], {x, 0, 1}]
 Plot[Piecewise[{{1, x == 1}, {0, 0 <= x < 1}}], {x, 0, 1.5}]
 Plot[Piecewise[{{1, x == 1}, {0, True}}], {x, 0, 1.5}]
```

All give  same result.  `x==1` does not show.

Clearly the sampling of the function "missed" the point `x=1`. The question is, should it?

Here is the same thing in Maple. Maple `piecewise` is just opposite of Mathematica. Instead of `value,condition` it uses `condition,value` and does not use `{}` to group them (which can be confusing first time using it)

```
f:=x->piecewise(x = 1, 1, true,0);
plot(f(x),x=0..1)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to make `Plot` Behave as Maple in this example? Did I do something wrong in my Mathematica code? Can Mathemartica's  plot result be considered correct?

Mathematica 12.0 on windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ParametricPlot` to show the jumps at the boundaries of the domain without having to extend the domain.

If jumps occur only at the boundaries using `ParametricPlot` solves the issue:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{.8, x == 0}, {1, x == 1}, {1/2, True}}]
ParametricPlot[{x, f1[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {-.5, 0}]
```

[image]

If there are jumps in the interior of the domain we need Ulrich's method using `PlotPoints` to force `ParametricPlot` to sample the specified points:

```
f2[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{.8, x == 0}, {1, x == 1}, {.2, x == .8}, {1/2, True}}]
ParametricPlot[{x, f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {-.5, 0}]
```

> same picture as above

With `ParametricPlot`, you don't have to include the boundaries in the list of jumps, that is, you can use `PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {.8}}` instead of `PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {0,.8,1}}`:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {.8}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {-.5, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.0001}, PlotPoints -> {Automatic, { 1}}]
```

[image]

Don't know why this workaround only works for extended plotrange.

Comment: very nice! this seems to be an undocumented feature. (+1)

Comment: undocumented, but very helpful!

Comment: i suggest you add this to [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/125)

Comment: Done, thanks for the hint!