# Plot not detecting integer values

Tags: plotting

While plotting `Plot[Ceiling[FractionalPart[x]], {x, 0, 3}]` I noticed that the dips at integers were not being plotted. Is there a way to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Probably not. Plot[] does discrete sampling and it’s unlikely it would detect the integer values. Further it tends to exclude discontinuities, so if detected, would skip them. Look up PlotPiecewise on this site for one approach

Comment: @MichaelE2 the code at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities/39466#39466 does the job but is mighty long. Is that the PlotPiecewise you alluded to or some in-built?

Comment: Yep, that’s it. It is long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the options `Exclusions`, `PlotPoints` and `Method` as follows:

```
Plot[Ceiling[FractionalPart[x]], {x, 0, 3},  
 PlotPoints -> {30, Range[0, 3]}, 
 Exclusions -> None, 
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `ParametricPlot` with the options `Exclusions` and `PlotPoints`:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, Ceiling[FractionalPart[x]]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
 PlotPoints -> {30, Range[0, 3]}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Note the special form of the option value for `PlotPoints` (see [see this answer by Ullrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200046/125)).

Comment: could you please explain what `PlotPoints -> {30, Range[0, 3]}` means?

Comment: @lineage, it says _sample 30 points in the domain but also include the points `{0,1,2,3}`_.

Comment: @kglr that’s a really neat undocumented feature! I’d never seen it before; thank for bringing it to my attention!